# How to call an external program and pass a string as a stdin to it in lua?

Tags: io, lua, stdin

I'm writing a simple script in Lua.  Here's where I got stuck: I'd like to call an external program and pass some string to it, so that it sees it as its `stdin`.  How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`io.popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) with mode `"w"`, it returns a file handler that you can write data to.

```
--test with the Lua interpreter
local f = io.popen("lua","w") 
f:write("print 'hello from Lua'") 
f:close()
```

Note that this function is system dependent and not available in all platforms.

Comment: OK, I'm rather a beginner in lua, so let me ask whether this is correct: `local f = io.popen("command","w")
f:write(mystring)
f:close()`

Comment: @mbork Exactly, try it. I modified your example a little and add it to the answer.